# Queue channel after integrator channel not working

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration for processing file. Here's my configuration

```
<int:channel id="startChannel">
<int:splitter input-channel="startChannel" output-channel="parseChannel" ref="splitter" method="split" />
<int:channel id="parseChannel">
    <int:queue size="50"/>
</int:channel>
<int:service-activator input-channel="parseChannel" output-channel="aggregatChannel" ref="process" method="process" />
 <int:channel id="aggregateChannel">  
     <int:queue size="50"/>
</int:channel>
<int:aggregate input-channel="aggregateChannel" output-channel="postProcessingChannel" ...(other attributes) />
<int:channel id="postProcessingChannel">  
     <int:queue size="50"/>
</int:channel>
<int:channel id="outboundChannel">  
     <int:queue size="50"/>
</int:channel>
<int:service-activator input-channel="postProcessingChannel" output-channel="outbound-channel" ... />
 <int:outbound-adapter channel="outputChannel" ... />

 ..global poller
 ..global taskexecutor of size 40
```

My configuration works fine till the aggregator. Aggregator is able to put messages at the `postProcessingChannel` but nobody is reading from the postProcessing Channel.

On a closer look, i observe - 
1) post processing channel is filled up with messages to its capacity.
2) threads are blocked in aggregator implementation, because they are not able to put messages in the postPostProcessing Channel.

My question is why no thread is reading from PostProcessingchannel ? From JProfiler I can see, many threads are idle/free not doing anything.

Can someone please help me understand this behavior.

Comment: Maybe your `service-activator` for the `postProcessingChannel` is marked with `auto-startup = "false" ?

Comment: No..its using default values..configuration is same for service activators before and after aggregator.

Comment: Well, the default task scheduler has a size 10. That looks like with all "only queues" design all the scheduler threads are busy. Try to increase its size or rethink your architecture do not use queues everywhere

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.8.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-taskscheduler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of queue channels; it is generally not necessary to make every channel a queue channel.

If you have more configuration, you are probably experiencing thread starvation in the default `taskScheduler` bean - it only has 10 threads by default.

If you have close to 10 queue channels in your application you will run out of threads because, by default, each queue channel will block a thread for 1 second (`receiveTimeout`).

Consider reducing the number of queue channels (as I said, it is not generally needed to have so many; you don't need to hand off to another thread between every component).

Or, see [Configuring the Task Scheduler](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-taskscheduler) to increase the available threads for scheduled tasks.

Comment: I am using a taskExecutor of size 40

Comment: I said `taskScheduler` not executor.

Comment: One follow up question: if I declare both task scheduler and task executor and assign task executor to the global poller. Then what will happen..? Here I expect scheduler to have sufficient threads to do scheduling and executor to have separate set of threads to execute messages

Comment: I am not ure what you question is; your expectation is correct.